# Problem with Java UDP server client Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I have a UDP server and many UDP clients (for hardware reasons, UDP is the only choice).

The UDP server accepts an incoming UDP connection on a default port and then assigns a new port to the client. It then starts a new thread (handler) with the new port to handle the client.

The client connects to the handler thread with the new port.

The client constantly feeds data to the handler thread.

The problem comes when I am trying to manage what will happen when the client goes down for whatever reason and then comes back up again.

I catch a datagramsocket exception and have tried various ways to terminate the handling thread.

The problem is that when the client is back up again, using the same port (must use the same port assigned to it), a new handler thread (i presume?) is started by the server and I get a java.net.BindException: Address is already in use: bind....

This is what I get (after the client goes down and back up again).
`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind ------------IOException was caught--------------`

I really don't understand how to unbind the datagramsocket in any different way.
The data flow is gone,
the socket times out,
the thread is stopped.
I've even used the deprecated .stop() method to make sure on a couple of runs.

Why is the socket still bound / in use ?

What can I do about it?

Anybody has any suggestions .. I am really stuck...

here is the Handler code ...

```
public class Handler implements Runnable, Serializable
 {

//Declaration stuff

    
public Handler (int con_port)
{
    
    port_number=con_port;

    
}  


public static void wait(int ms)
{
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    
    
    
}



public void write() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("testing.tmp");
    ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(data_list);
    oos.close();

}

public void write(String fname) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fname);
    ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(data_list);
    oos.close();
}

    public void run()
    {
        
        while(running)
        {
        
        try
        {
            DatagramSocket socket =new DatagramSocket(port_number);
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        DatagramPacket packet;
        byte[] buf = new byte[32];
        packet = new DatagramPacket (buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive (packet);
        String received = new String (packet.getData());
    
        String data[]= received.split("/");
        
        //Do things with incoming data
        
        socket.close();
        
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            

            System.out.println("------------IOException was caught--------------");
            running=false;
        }
        
        System.out.println("This is the Handler Thread Id:"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
       

    }

}
```

I tried to use :

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort));
```

but when I use that, I get even more unexplained behavior where I get a socket timeout exception even though the client is feeding data normally..
On that front, java is picking up my VM GNS3 nic IP addresses and does not pick up my actual NIC IP address, which is weird... I have to add that manually if I am using the above way..

Answer (score 0):

A DatagramSocket listens forever also if there no incoming traffic. If the client goes down the server has no way to understand what happens (whit TCP connection you can).

The only moment in which the server can "understand" the problem is when a client reconnect. I think that a possible approach is to keep a Map of active port/Handler in the main thread and do one of these two thing:

- reuse the previous  connection/threads/Handler passing the same port to the client without creating a new thread. The server side thread will be still alive.
- kill the previous  connection/threads/Handler closing the socket from outside (you must expose a method). This will generate a IOException in  socket.receive (packet); line and the thread will exit. Then you can create a new one without problems